# Microsoft.Excel9.Interop Reference Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, office-interop, excel-interop

I've been tasked to work on an existing .Net 2.0 Visual Studio 2012 project which contains a reference to Microsoft.Excel9.Interop, but the reference is throwing undefined errors on my machine.

I haven't been able to find anything in my research about how to solve this error or where I can find Microsoft.Excel9.Interop dll.

Does anyone have any experience with Microsoft.Excel9.Interop that can point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install, in this order:

1. Microsoft Office
2. Visual Studio Tools for Office which installs the [PIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)'s, this installs all the assemblies you need

Are you sure you are looking for version 9? This is for Office 2000.

Comment: I'd actually like to convert this project to .Net Framework 4.5 if possible.

Comment: @TrevorBrooks: Check this out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2013/03/06/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-now-available.aspx.